# How do I copy percision formatting to text file?

Tags: c++, text, output

I cannot figure out how to copy the formatting I have for text in the console window that I am also copying to a text file to turn in for a grade.

The text file I am using is named csis.

I have tried replacing cout with csis for the same line, which normally works.

However, this gives an error: namespace std has no member csis, which makes sense.  So, how do I copy the same presisions to the text file csis?

```
//example of function with the problem
//print percentage of pairs dealt
void Game1::printPairsPercentage() {
    pairHands = pairs / hands;
    std::cout << std::fixed;
    std::csis << std::fixed;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::csis << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << setw(15) << pairHands << "%" << endl;
    std::csis << setw(15)<< pairHands << "%" << endl;
```

//error: namespace std has no member Csis

Comment: Where did you define `csis`?

Comment: `csis << std::fixed;`? It's not clear why you think you need `std::`.

Comment: put your whole file with includes

Comment: Read about `ofstream`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a file outstream and then outputting to the file, something like this:

```
#include <fstream>

//example of function with the problem
//print percentage of pairs dealt
void Game1::printPairsPercentage() {
    std::ofstream csis("Path to text file");
    pairHands = pairs / hands;
    csis << std::fixed;
    csis << std::fixed;
    csis << std::setprecision(2);
    csis << std::setprecision(2);
    csis << setw(15) << pairHands << "%" << endl;
    csis << setw(15)<< pairHands << "%" << endl;
}
```